# Create Process запуск процесса

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, процесс

После ввода - 1, должно запускаться второй exe, но не работает, подскажите где ошибка

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

void _tmain()
{
    int a;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USEPOSITION | STARTF_USESIZE;
    si.dwX = 100;
    si.dwY = 100;
    si.dwXSize = 100;
    si.dwYSize = 100;
    TCHAR szCmdLine[] = L"C:\\Users\\Viktoria\\Desktop\\univ\\III Курс\\Операційні системи\\lab6\\Debug\\lab6.exe";
    cout << "enter - ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 1)
    {
        CreateProcess(szCmdLine, NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            CREATE_SUSPENDED,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi)
            ;

            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else cout << "Shh";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А "не работает" - это значит что происходит? Если зависает на `WaitForSingleObject`, то все правильно. Вы же процесс создали с флагом `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, то есть он у вас создается, но не выполняется, ждет когда вы его снимете с паузы. А вы вместо этого следующей командой ждете когда он завершится. А он все никак не завершится, потому что все никак не стартует.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот вторую программу открывает в этой же, как открыть в новом консольном окне?

Comment: @obd obd, Вместо `CREATE_SUSPENDED` укажите флаг `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.